# Salvar apenas dia e mês em campo DATE em mysql com php?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso cadastrar datas comemorativas no banco de dados, mas preciso apenas do dia e mês, o ano não é relevante e não precisa ser cadastrado.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte, consigo salvar apenas o dia e o mês no campo `Date do MYSQL`? ou melhor salvar em campo texto? E depois recuperar com a função `date do php`, pois vou precisar fazer uma função para calcular que a data está próxima quanto faltar apenas 5 dias para a mesma.
Exemplo:

```html
<label>Nome Data:
<input type="text" name="data_comemorativa"/>
</label>
<br><br>
<label>Data:
<input type="text" placeholder="dia / mês" name="data"/>
</label>
<br><br>
<button name="Salvar">Salvar</button>

<!--
Depois em php farei a busca no banco todos os dias e farei um alerta para quando estiver faltando apenas 5 dias para o evento e alertado até o dia do evento
"falta 5 dias para...."
"falta 4 dias para ..."
"até o dia do evento"

para o calculo em php vou pegar o ano atual mais o dia e mes vindo do banco.
-->
```

Ou melhor salvar o dia e mês com o ano corrente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pessoalmente eu guardaria com o ano corrente em formato de `Date`.

O *MySql* tem funções de data para retirar só o mês ou o dia de uma data por isso dá para fazer os cálculos todos na mesma, e se por algum motivo precisar da data toda ela está lá para se poder utilizar.

Comment: Perfeito @Isac, estava na dúvida se faria assim mesmo.